# Error moving aside element when created at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to create a program for one of my games(details not needed) nevertheless I can move around aside elements written in the code
`<aside draggable="true" class="dragme" data-item="0">One</aside>`

but if I create it at runtime(via button click) it gives me this error in the console
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`

Here is my full code anybody have ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
aside {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.second {
 left: 100px;
 top: 100px;
}

body, html {
 min-height: 100vh;
}

body{
 width:700px;
 height:700px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body ondragover="drag_over(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
<div class="ControlPanel">
<button onclick="CreateNew('item1')">Item1</button>
</div>
<aside draggable="true" class="dragme" data-item="0">One</aside>


<script>
var dataNum = 0;
function CreateNew(item){
 if(item == "item1"){
  dataNum += 1;
  var asi = document.createElement("ASIDE");
  asi.setAttribute("draggable",true);
  asi.setAttribute("class","dragme second");
  asi.setAttribute("data-item",dataNum);
  asi.setAttribute("style","left: 347px; top: 82px;");
  document.body.appendChild(asi);
 }
}

function drag_start(event) {
 var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
 event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
}

function drag_over(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
}

function drop(event) {
 var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
 var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
 dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
 dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
}

var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
for (var i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
 dm[i].addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
 document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
 document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering the event listener only once during the page load. Therefore, when you create a new element, you need to re-register the events for the newly created elements too.

```
<script>
    var dataNum = 0;
    function CreateNew(item){
        if(item == "item1"){
            dataNum += 1;
            var asi = document.createElement("ASIDE");
            asi.setAttribute("draggable",true);
            asi.setAttribute("class","dragme second");
            asi.setAttribute("data-item",dataNum);
            asi.setAttribute("style","left: 347px; top: 82px;");
            document.body.appendChild(asi);
        registerDragMe(); // --> Add this
        }
    }

    function drag_start(event) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY) + ',' + event.target.getAttribute('data-item'));
    }

    function drag_over(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    function drop(event) {
        var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
        var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
        dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
        dm[parseInt(offset[2])].style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // create a wrapper function
    function registerDragMe(){
    var dm = document.getElementsByClassName('dragme');
    for (var i = 0; i < dm.length; i++) {
        dm[i].addEventListener('dragstart', drag_start, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('dragover', drag_over, false);
        document.body.addEventListener('drop', drop, false);
    }
    }

    registerDragMe();
    </script>
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/jcLjr70y/